# AlwaysRunning is not starting site properly

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have set up my application pool with Start Mode = AlwaysRunning

Additionally, I have added the following to my `web.config` file

```
<applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true" skipManagedModules="false">
  <add initializationPage="/" hostName="example.com" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

The site has almost no requests, apart from the site requesting itself through Hangfire, so I would like the site to start itself whenever it recycles.

In the Event Viewer I see entries like this:

```
08:09: A worker process with process id of '2564' serving application pool 'FoobarAppPool' has requested a recycle because the worker process reached its allowed processing time limit.
```

That's fine. It matches my applications own logs of a shutdown being initialized.

But then it is followed by this every 20 minutes for a few hours:

```
08:29: A worker process with process id of '3012' serving application pool 'FoobarAppPool' was shutdown due to inactivity.  Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes.  A new worker process will be started when needed.
```

This seems to indicate that a new worker process is indeed started. But my applications logs show nothing, and the ram/cpu usage is very low at this time.

Then after a few hours, the site will start consuming ram/cpu again, and the logs start showing activity. This "silent" period seems to last everywhere from 1 to 6 hours.

Am I missing something here?

Running on IIS 10, Windows Server 2016, on an Azure VM.

Comment: Why do you want the site to always run?

Comment: @mason The site has some scheduled tasks that it needs to perform (via Hangfire), so that it is ready for the requests that it does need to serve. So I basically want the site to warm itself up instantly after a recycle, and stay alive until the next scheduled recycle.

Comment: @mortenbock. A website is not meant to schedule tasks that must run at specific times. Create a Windows service for that or use the Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Exactly my point. You can embed Hangfire in a Windows Service (possibly hosted via [TopShelf](https://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview/index.html)). Don't do it in a website, even if it's kinda capable of it.

Comment: This does not change the fact that the feature that IIS provides does not seem to be working. The url supplied in initializationPage is never called.

The answer to a feature not working cannot be "don't use the feature".

Comment: Yes, it certainly can be. I've found that feature to be unreliable. It also doesn't make sense to embed long running or scheduled tasks inside of a web application. They rightfully belong in a separate process. No, this doesn't directly resolve your issue but it is the correct solution.

Comment: @mason Creating a separate windows service certainly does not solve the problem of instantly warming up a web applications cache after an application pool recycle. Long running tasks or not, there is a valid scenario for wanting to keep a website alive.

Comment: The solution isn't to ensure that the website always stays alive. It *will* go down. You will just have to reinitialize your cache when that happens. No computer process should be designed with the expectation that it can't go down. You should embrace it and plan for it.

Comment: @mason Yes of course it can go down. But when it does, the IIS has the feature to start it back up. That way the IIS takes the hit of warming up the site instead of the first client to hit the site afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the issue originated in the rewrite rules for the site.

The site runs https, so there was a rewrite rule to redirect all http traffic to https.

The `initializationPage` url will be called over http, so the rule needs to be adjusted to not redirect that initial request to https, since the IIS will not follow the redirect, but just accept the 301/302 statuscode.